# deserializeJson, String can not left blank

Tags: c++, json, deserialization

When I `deserializeJson()` a string in C++:

```
StaticJsonDocument<800> doc;
deserializeJson(doc, payload);
const char* something = doc["something"];
Serial.printf("something: %s",something);
```

The `something` string cannot left blank, otherwise my Arduino crashes. Does this have to do with null-termination? How can I work around this? I now always send some string information into my object.

not:

```json
{"hours":20,"minutes":54,"seconds":35}
```

but:

```json
{"hours":20,"minutes":54,"seconds":35,"something":"Nederland"}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `doc["something"]` does not find a JSON element named `something`, is a `NULL` pointer returned? It is likely *undefined behavior* to pass a `NULL` pointer to `printf("%s")`, so check for `NULL` beforehand, eg:

```
const char* something = doc["something"];
if (something) {
    Serial.printf("something: %s",something);
}
```

Otherwise, assign `""` to `something` if it is `NULL`, eg:

```
const char* something = doc["something"];
if (!something) something = "";
Serial.printf("something: %s", something);
```

Or, do the check for `NULL` directly in the `printf()` call:

```
const char* something = doc["something"];
Serial.printf("something: %s", (something) ? something : "");
```

Comment: yes! I now do:     if (!something==0) {   
Serial.printf("something %s",something); }    This works!

Comment: `if (!something == 0)` is treated as `if ((!something) == 0)`, which works, but would be better written as `if (something != 0)` instead, or simply as `if (something)`. Readability is important for maintaining code over time.